# Drupal 6 --> Drupal 7 Migration field und's

Tags: drupal

In drupal 6 to get a node field's value you would do:

```
$node->field_ajax_override[0]['value']
```

Now it is:

```
$node->field_ajax_override['und'][0]['value']
```

Is this just going to be a pain to migrate or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo render($content['field_ajax_override']);` instead in Drupal 7 (amongst other ways)

The article [Rendering Drupal 7 Fields the right way](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) discusses why accessing variables through ['und'] is bad. See the below excerpt.

> Firstly, the ['und'] element is part of the field localisation in
>   Drupal 7 (see this article from Gábor Hojtsy for more on that);
>   directly accessing that value will cause issues in any kind of
>   multi-lingual environment. Boo.
>
> By accessing the field value directly you miss out on any theming that
>   might come courtesy of the normal field markup.
>
> The [0][safe_value] explicitly accesses the first value of the field -
>   if you wanted every value from a multi-value field you'd need to do
>   some sort of loop.
>
> Some fields (such as node references) won't have a safe_value element,
>   only a value - which can easily be printed without thought for
>   sanitisation. This is dangerous, not because node reference fields
>   contain dangerous data (they're just a nid), but because it's not a
>   helpful habit to get into, especially for new developers. Other fields
>   types 'value' may well be highly dangerous.

The article then goes on to advocate the use of `field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_name');` but in most cases `render($content['field']);` will be sufficient, particularly if you already have access to the node you're rendering, for example in the node.tpl.php file or one of it's variations.

Comment: Not sure about your comment as can only see "But if we are doing $node = node_load(1); then"- if you were to do $loaded_node = node_load(1); you could then do field_view_field('node', $loaded_node, 'field_name'); to access that field.